# PHP mention system with usernames with space

Tags: php, html

I wanted to know if it's possible to make a PHP mention system with usernames with space ?
I tried this

```
preg_replace_callback('#@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#', 'mentionUser', htmlspecialchars_decode($r['content']))
```

My function:

```
    function mentionUser($matches) {
    global $db;
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ?');
    $req->execute(array($matches[1]));

    if($req->rowCount() == 1) {
        $idUser = $req->fetch()['id'];
        return '<a class="mention" href="members/profile.php?id='.$idUser.'">'.$matches[0].'</a>'; 
    }
    return $matches[0];
```

It works, but not for the usernames with space...
I tried to add `\s`, it works, but not well, the preg_replace_callback detect the username and the other parts of the message, so the mention don't appear...
Is there any solution ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you `str_replace()` each `[SPACE]` to a placeholder like `+` and then `str_replace` back again when you return the markup?

Comment: You want to limit it to just a single space, so I think `@(\w+(?:\s\w+)?)` is what you are looking for? I swapped to the character class of `\w` which is the same as yours but also allows underscores, you could swap back easily

Comment: The solution of Chris Haas work, but there is a problem, if there is "@Mention [some text]", the mention don't work...

Comment: I said it for his comment, and not his answer, because the answer works as I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said that you just removed the ability to add a space, but I still wanted to post a solution. To be clear, I don't necessarily think you should use this code, because it probably is just easier to keep things simple, but I think it should work still.

Your major problem is that almost *every* mention will incur two lookups because `@bob johnson went to the store` could be either `bob` or `bob johnson` and there's no way to determine that without going to the databases. Caching will greatly reduce this problem, luckily.

Below is some code that generally does what you are looking for. I made a fake database using just an array for clarity and reproducibility. The inline code comments should hopefully make sense.

```php
function mentionUser($matches)
{
    // This is our "database" of users
    $users = [
        'bob johnson',
        'edward',
    ];
    
    // First, grab the full match which might be 'name' or 'name name'
    $fullMatch = $matches['username'];

    // Create a search array where the key is the search term and the value is whether or not
    // the search term is a subset of the value found in the regex
    $names = [$fullMatch => false];
    
    // Next split on the space. If there isn't one, we'll have an array with just a single item
    $maybeTwoParts = explode(' ', $fullMatch);
    
    // Basically, if the string contained a space, also search only for the first item before the space,
    // and flag that we're using a subset
    if (count($maybeTwoParts) > 1) {
        $names[array_shift($maybeTwoParts)] = true;
    }

    foreach ($names as $name => $isSubset) {
        
        // Search our "database"
        if (in_array($name, $users, true)) {
            
            // If it was found, wrap in HTML
            $ret = '<span>@' . $name . '</span>';
            
            // If we're in a subset, we need to append back on the remaining string, joined with a space
            if ($isSubset) {
                $ret .= ' ' . array_shift($maybeTwoParts);
            }

            return $ret;
        }
    }
    
    // Nothing was found, return what was passed in
    return '@' . $fullMatch;
}

// Our search pattern with an explicitly named capture
$pattern = '#@(?<username>\w+(?:\s\w+)?)#';

// Three tests
assert('hello <span>@bob johnson</span> test' === preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'mentionUser', 'hello @bob johnson test'));
assert('hello <span>@edward</span> test' === preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'mentionUser', 'hello @edward test'));
assert('hello @sally smith test' === preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'mentionUser', 'hello @sally smith test'));
```

Comment: With this, it's possible to update the mention if the user change his name please ?

Comment: Once you find an @-mention, you should mark it with something like a `data` attribute of the user's ID, such as `<a data-user-id="1234">user</a>` since you already know that. On page render, you'll have to decide what logic works for your business case. For instance, if I change my display name on this site today, should my 10+ years of mentions change, too? As long as the link still finds me, I'm personally fine with my mention name staying with the old one. To me, @-mention is point in time and historical, unaffected by future changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+( *[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/g
```

It will find an at sign first, and then try to find one or more letter or numbers. It will try to find zero or more inner spaces and zero or more letters and numbers coming after that.

I am assuming the username only contains A-Za-z0-9 and space.

Comment: Hummm, when I try this, the replies doesn't appear

Comment: @Lunyx You should be giving more context since "replies doesn't appear" doesn't give any clue about what's going on in your code to me.